# android:Assign array of digits to arraylist of objects

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I have an Arraylist of ImageView and an array of numbers for example:

```
ArrayList<ImageView> imageViews = new ArrayList<>();

int[] numbers = new int[]{6,8};
```

I want for each index of numbers get an ImageView(one by one- index1 numbers= index1 imageviews...) and then check what is the digit of each index and put a drawable for that image view

Comment: It's not clear to me what exactly you want. Can you please elaborate a little.

Comment: * I am new in programming * sorry for my bad English\\\1-I am getting a number of user separate it to digits 2- with a for loop I am getting all image views in activities and put them in an araylist(.imagview1 imagview2... )3- I have assets with subfolder 0~9 into the project\\\Now in an if else I am checking digits and for each number from 0~9 assign a GIF animation to an imageview( if 1 imagview1 if 2 imagview2....) If user put 4587... it is ok But if user put 1122 I have problem so I need to write a code that use image view's base of index of digits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you are trying to take a `String` of numbers, and place an image into an `ImageView` based on what numbers the user entered. I think I would need more information to answer your question fully, but I will answer as best I can with the information provided.

So to start off, I believe you already separated the `String` input into an array of `int` objects. So now you have an array of integers, an `ArrayList` of `Drawable` resources and an `ArrayList` of `ImageView` objects. Now you want to place a `Drawable` in each `ImageView` corresponding to each digit in the integer array. Assuming duplicate `Drawable` images are okay, you can just iterate through your integer array and place the `Drawable` for each digit:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    imageViews.get(i).setImageDrawable(drawables.get(numbers[i]));
}
```